# Android WebView CSS filter issue

Tags: android, html, css, webview, webkit

I'm seeing a weird issue using the CSS `filter` attribute in my WebView.
I have a WebView as part of a ViewPager. That WebView has a `filter` CSS  attribute with `grayscale` [it also has a corresponding `-webkit-filter` attribute].

The issue I'm seeing is that when I drag my finger left or right on the WebView, the filter attribute disappears and the elements on the page can be seen at full color. But if I drag up and down, the grayscale re-appears.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Lollipop.

Is there a way to avoid that? I need the gray scale to be there all the time.
Or is there another way to implement grayscale in Android WebViews?

Any help is appreciated!